# Connect POP3 account with vb.net

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

My English may fail because I am Brazilian.
I intend to connect a .NET application (DLL or Console) to a POP3 account and extract attachments from a particular email.

I intend to do this and integrate with SQL Server to automate routines that today is done manually.

PS: Who is always sends the same e-mail and the attachment is a ZIP format with the day's date in the file name.

Comment: What is your question? Where is the code that gives you problems? Please post what have you tried otherwise it is like you are just asking for someone to write code for you.

Comment: You may find it easier without the language barrier over at [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET Framework Base Class Library does not natively support the POP3 protocol.

Thus, you have the following options:

1. You use the [TcpClient class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a TCP connection to the POP3 server and implement the [POP3 protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) yourself (it's not very complicated, if you only need a simple subset such as retrieving e-mail contents) or
2. you look for a third-party library. Since software recommendations are off-topic here, I will not recommend a particular one, but a quick Google search for `pop3 .net` yields plenty of results and [here's an old SO question which *does* have recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426388).

Note: To unzip the attachments, you can use the [ZipArchive class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) if you are targeting .NET 4.5 or higher. Otherwise, you will need a third-party library for that as well.